# Typescript: Why doesn't inner function resolve the arguments on outer function?

Tags: javascript, promise, closures, arrow-functions

Please look at the following code:

```
function myfunc(name: string): void {
        var p = getPromise(**url**):Promise<string>;
        p.then((data:string) => {
           console.log(data);
           console.log(name);
        });
    }

myfunc("John");
```

When I run the code, I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: name is not defined

I don't understand why. The arrow function is inside the big function 
'myfunc', and therefore, the arrow function is supposed to have access to the variables of the wrapper function. Why doesn't it happen in this case?

Comment: You need to pass a async function inside a promise

Comment: this isn't valid javascript

Comment: Are you sure this is correct javascript code?

Comment: getPromise is a function that I wrote, but this code works as I described.

Comment: You should try without all these flow stuff. This code works correctly in ES6.

Comment: check this example https://jsfiddle.net/b25rm0j5/ `name` can be accessed in then callback

Comment: Both a normal function and an arrow function have access to the variables of the scope they where defined in, thats how closures and scopes work. An arrow function unlike regulate a function, does not bind its own `this` and `arguments`, but that is not relevant in your code.

Comment: Other than the `:Promise<string` part, which I assume is some sort of type assertion, your code is fine and should work, so there's something you're not telling us.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the declaration of p into more of a typescript using let. The rest should be same.

```
function myfunc(name: string): void {
    let p:Promise<string> = getPromise(**url**);
    p.then((data:string) => {
       console.log(data);
       console.log(name);
    });
    return p;
}
```

Comment: What did you change? Why? What was the problem? Please [edit] your answer to include an explanation besides the code.

Comment: Ok. Updated it.

Comment: Well `let` vs `var` does not make a difference here, so it won't solve the problem.

Comment: Definitely, it won't (in the sense of let vs. var) but I changed the declaration because he had it switched between the type and the method.